# Changing HTML Data Before Page Rendering

Tags: javascript

I've been searching for an answer to this and can't seem to find out how to do it...or if it is possible.

I have a JavaScript Program that displays an .HTML page.  I have an API from another company that sends us information as well.  I would like to be able to change the contents of the .HTML page before the user sees it.  Is this possible?

For example, suppose page.html is:

```
<HTML>
<HEADER>
<TITLE>
The Company Name
</TITLE>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
Some stuff
</BODY>
</<HTML>
```

page.html is housed on our server and using JavaScript/HTML I would like to change the value of "The Company Name" with the value from the API before the page is rendered to the user.  Is this possible?

Comment: Which server side scripting language are you using ?

Comment: Since the title can show up before the page has even downloaded completely, there is no good client-side method that will work reliably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Javascript function will do the trick:

```
window.onload = function() { document.getElementByTagNames("title")[0].value = "Yourvalue"; }
```

Comment: Could I use this technique to replace the whole document with an entire html page like:  "<html>...entire document...</html>" if I had this in a variable? How would I do that?

Comment: I am not sure you can replace the entire HTML. However, you can in succession, change all the contents of each tag, like `script`, `body`, etc. That should do. For example, if you wrap your entire `body` inside another `div` with id **wrapper**, you can say `document.body.removeChild('document.getElementById('wrapper'))`.

Answer (score 2):

`window.onload` would not do the trick if you want to be sure that your users don't see the page  before edition, as `onload` waits for everything to be loaded, including images.

What I recommend is :

- to change the title in a block in the head : `<script>document.title="test"</script>`
- to hide initially the page, by enclosing it in a `<div id=wholepage style="display:none;">`
- to change the page content in a standard `<script>` block included at the end of your body
- to render your big div visible at end, using `document.getElementById('wholepage').style.display='block';`

Answer (score 0):

You could load the HTML from the page into a string variable. Then you'd use regex on the string and search for the starting expression  and ending expression , and do a replace on that content. Javascript has a replace method.

```
var str="<HTML><HEADER><TITLE>The Company Name</TITLE></HEADER><BODY>Some stuff</BODY></<HTML>";
str=str.replace("<TITLE>","<DUMMY>"); 
str=str.replace("</TITLE>","</DUMMY><TITLE>your real title</TITLE>");
```

Essentially you would rename the title tag into a non existent tag like dummy, then append the real title tag to the end of it.

Then you can display the HTML content in the string/variable in a page at runtime.

Comment: How do you load the HTML from a page on the server into a string variable?  I can't seem to find the commands to do that?