# Remove HTML attribute before rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to remove `src` attribute for each `img` tag before image is fetched ?
I want to change image fetching behavior.

What I did:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.removeAttr('src');
    // ... my custom actions
});
```

What happened:
Image is fetched, before `src` attribute is removed :/

Thanks

Comment: Have your tried to accomplish this on your own yet? Please post specific code and any issues you are having.

Comment: I updated my post, I used jQuery to remove attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing HTML Data Before Page Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410895/changing-html-data-before-page-rendering)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your src is in the markup then it will fetch before your js execute. Simply don't use `src` attribute, put the src in say `data-src`, then grab it with js and do what you want to do.

Comment: This is i want to avoid because the project I am working on is very big. But I realized that there is no solution except changing `src` attributes to data-* manually. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: If you are worried about SEO, you could also use an anchor tag with the href pointing to the image and then use js to change them into image tags. This way you  will have better seo because the image will be indexed and you are not loading them on load. In our own project, we use a div tag with all the info needed in data attributes then output the right image depending on screen size